# How to make webpage act like a subdirectory with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm building a website which has a profile page for each user.

I'd like the profile pages to be accessed through visiting a web address, eg:

```
example.com/profile/username
```

Obviously it would be impractical to create a new PHP file for each registered user, and so what I'm trying to do is redirect traffic from `example.com/profile/(whatever)` to `example.com/profile`, where I can then interrogate the URL and load the correct profile from a database.

However, I'm really struggling to work out how to do this with `.htaccess`. I've tried all sorts of redirects, etc, but can't seem to get it to work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The only other thing I've got in my `.htaccess` file at the moment is the below to remove `.php` from URLs:

```
# Remove .php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Any advice gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> redirect traffic from `example.com/profile/(whatever)` to `example.com/profile`

Note that you should internally rewrite directly to the file that handles the request, which I assume is `/profile.php`, rather than relying on another rewrite to later append the extension. I assume that code in `/profile.php` already processes the request as necessary.

I will also assume that "username" can consist only of the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` (underscore) and `-` (hyphen). Generally, you want to be as specific as possible.

Try something like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Disable MultiViews to avoid conflicts with mod_negotiation
# (Since you are using "extensionless URLs")
Options -MultiViews

# Handle requests for `/profile/<username>
RewriteRule ^profile/([\w-]+)$ profile.php [L]

# Append the ".php" extension to any request that does not end in a file extension
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Whilst the comment in your code states "Remove .php". The code actually *appends* the file extension to URLs that don't have one.

This currently only works for files in the document root (as per your original code), eg. `/foo`. It won't do anything with `/foo/bar` for instance.

The condition that checks against the file system (ie. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`) was not required in your existing code, unless you have actual files that don't contain a file extension? I'm also assuming you do not need to access filesystem directories directly (as per your original code).

There is no need to escape literal dots when used inside a character class.